Issue in Jenkins Pipeline
I’m in the process of migrating my CI/CD pipeline from GitHub Actions to Jenkins. I’ve set up the Jenkins server and configured Git. My current project is built with Node.js and uses numerous environment variables, which are stored in a .env file. I’ve uploaded these variables as secrets in Jenkins credentials and am trying to access them in my Jenkins pipeline.
When building the project, Jenkins uses the Dockerfile, which includes a command to migrate the database using Prisma. Prisma relies on the DATABASE_URL variable specified in the .env file. However, this environment variable is not being properly loaded in the Jenkins pipeline.
Here is my pipeline configuration:
pipeline {
    agent any

     environment {
        registry = "my_ecr_registry"
    }

    stages {
        stage('Load Environment') {
            steps {
                script {
                    withCredentials([file(credentialsId: 'my_credentail_id', variable: 'ENV_FILE')]) {
                        def envContents = readFile(ENV_FILE)
                        def envVars = envContents.split('\n').collectEntries { line ->
                            def parts = line.split('=')
                            if (parts.size() == 2) {
                                [(parts[0].trim()): parts[1].trim()]
                            } else {
                                [:]
                            }
                        }


                        envVars.each { key, value ->
                            env."${key}" = value
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        stage('Print All Environment Variables') {
            steps {
                script {
                    sh 'env'
                }
            }
        }



        stage('Checkout Code') {
            steps {
                git branch: 'dev',
                url: 'my_github_url.git',
                credentialsId: 'my_credentail_id'
            }
        }

        stage('Building image') {
            steps {
                script {
                    docker.build(
                        "${registry}:dev_latest",
                        "--build-arg DATABASE_URL=${DATABASE_URL} ."
                    )
                    echo "Build successful"
                }
            }
        }

        // }

        stage('Configure AWS Credentials') {
            steps {
                sh '''
                    aws configure set aws_access_key_id ${AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID}
                    aws configure set aws_secret_access_key ${AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY}
                    aws configure set region us-east-1
                '''
            }
        }

        stage('Login to ECR') {
            steps {
                sh '''
                    aws ecr get-login-password --region us-east-1 | docker login --username AWS --password-stdin ${ECR_REGISTRY}
                '''
            }
        }

        stage('Push Docker Image') {
            steps {
                sh '''
                    docker-compose push
                '''
            }
        }

        stage('Deploy to Development Server') {
            steps {
                sshagent(['jenkins-ssh-key']) {
                    sh """
                        ssh -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no ${USERNAME}@${HOST_NAME_DEV} '
                            sudo docker system prune -a -f
                            sudo docker pull ${ECR_REGISTRY}/project:dev_latest
                            cd /home/ubuntu/project
                            bash docker-pull.sh
                        '
                    """
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

I need the Jenkins pipeline to build the code, push it to Amazon ECR, and deploy the project to an EC2 instance.

You are assigning the environment variables correctly
                            env."${key}" = value

but then you are using normal Groovy variables in the string interpolation
                        "--build-arg DATABASE_URL=${DATABASE_URL} ."

You should reference the environment variable you have just assigned
                        "--build-arg DATABASE_URL=${env.DATABASE_URL} ."

When you are using single quotes (or triple single quotes) it works as expected because Groovy doesn't interpolate ${} expressions
                sh '''
                    aws ecr get-login-password --region us-east-1 | docker login --username AWS --password-stdin ${ECR_REGISTRY}
                '''


(--build-arg DATABASE_URL (no value) would work too.)

@Biffen interesting! How? Would the resulting docker command know to pick an environment variable with the same name?

Yes. As per the documentation: ‘You can also use the --build-arg flag without a value, in which case the daemon propagates the value from the local environment into the Docker container it's building’.

Despite passing the DATABASE_URL with the argument --build-arg DATABASE_URL=${env.DATABASE_URL}, I am still encountering the following error when running npx prisma migrate dev:
Prisma schema loaded from prisma/schema.prisma
Datasource "db": PostgreSQL database

Error: Prisma schema validation - (get-config wasm)
Error code: P1012
error: Environment variable not found: DATABASE_URL.
  -->  schema.prisma:11
   | 
10 |   provider = "postgresql"
11 |   url      = env("DATABASE_URL")

@Iterokun

I'm also unsure if I need to pass all the environment variables that my application uses into the Jenkins pipeline. Sorry, I'm new to Jenkins.

@ajay, the pipeline you have in your question pushes and pull two different images. This is going to devolve into a back and forth troubleshooting session. I offer consulting services though :)
